# Django - User Search

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to filter `ListView` based on post method from search bar in my `base`template. So making it works like:

```
 Insert name --> SearchBar-->GET Method-->SearchView class(in views.py)--> render html with usernames.
```

I have done this, but it wont work. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

views.py in my user app

```py
class SearchView(ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'blog/list_of_users.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_search_results'

    def get_queryset(self):
       result = super(SearchView, self).get_queryset()
       query = self.request.GET.get('search')
       if query:
          postresult = User.objects.filter(username__contains=query)
          result = postresult
       else:
           result = None
       return result
```

urls.py in my `blog` app

```
path('users_search/?search=<str:username>', user_view.SearchView.as_view(), name='user_search'),
```

search form in html

```py
  <form class="example" method="GET">
                <input type="search" placeholder="ユーザー検索..." name="user_name">
                  <button type="submit">
                    検索
                  </button>
```

rendered html with user names

```py
{% for result in all_search_results %}
   {{ result.username }}
{% empty %}
   add something to show no results
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you want to use get method or post method?

Comment: #Nalin Dobhal the one that will works :D Which should I take?

Comment: change `<input type="search" placeholder="ユーザー検索..." name="user_name">` to `<input type="search" placeholder="ユーザー検索..." name="search">` and check if it is working

Comment: no, it doesnt redirect me, it only inserts "?search=marcel" at the end of the link

Comment: try defining the `action` attribute in your form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override `get_context_data` method

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    user_name = self.request.GET.get('user_name', '')
    context['all_search_results'] = User.objects.filter(username__icontains=user_name )
    return context
```

In your `template`

```
<form class="example" method="GET">
    <input type="text" placeholder="ユーザー検索..." name="user_name">
    <button type="submit">
        検索
     </button>
</form>

{% for result in all_search_results %}
   {{ result.username }}
{% empty %}
   add something to show no results
{% endfor %}
```

**Update**:

in `template`, `<input ........... name="search">`

in `views`, `user_name = self.request.GET.get('search', '')`

Comment: thanks! This worked, I have a link like .../users_search/?search=marcel, but it shows all users, not "marcel" only

Comment: it doesnt redirect me, my path is "path('users_search/', user_view.SearchView.as_view(), name='user_name'),"